# How to extract an order by clause so I can use logic to set it?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to extract out an OrderBy clause, is this possible?

So I can do something like:

```
OrderBy ob = null;

if(....)
  ob = x.Id
else
  ob = x.Name


var result = source.OrderBy(ob);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm guessing it depends on why you would want to do this. @p.s.w.g answer describes the most practical scenario.

Answer (score 6):

You could do something that would map almost exactly to what you're doing, but the easier option is to keep track of the query, not the method to order on:

```
IQueryable<Whatever> query = someQuery;

if(something)
    query = query.OrderBy(item => item.Id);
else
    query = query.OrderBy(item => item.Name);
```

However, if you really want to:

```
Expression<Func<Whatever, object>> selector = null;

if(something)
    selector = item => item.Id;
else
    selector = item => item.Name;

var results = query.OrderBy(selector);
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the second option only works for Linq-to-Objects.

Comment: @p.s.w.g You'd just need to change it to an `Expression<Func<...>>` to handle that.

Comment: I considered that, but still, you'd probably have to make sure each expression had the same type. I don't think `Expression<Func<Whatever, object>>` would work.

Comment: @p.s.w.g I've done it before without any problems.  I suppose it's possible that certain query providers in certain situations might have a problem, but in general it should work, and the first option is there for those handful of edge cases that might have a problem.

Comment: Hmm, I just tried it in LINQPad. With Linq-to-SQL I got "*Cannot order by type 'System.Object'.*", and with EF I got "*Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.*". You could probably get around that with a little reflection, but that doesn't seem too practical. Still, you might be right that it will work with some other Linq providers.

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like this:

```
IQueryable<Foo> result = source ...
if(....)
  result = result.OrderBy(x => x.Id);
else
  result = result.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do your conditional logic and do the separate OrderBy() based on the conditon?

Ex.

```
if(foo == true)
{
result = result.OrderBy(r => r.Id);
}
else
{
result = result.OrderBy(r => r.Name);
}
```